# contar filas actualizadas o insertadas trigger

Tags: postgresql, trigger, function

estoy queriendo contar filas actualizadas o insertadas que pertenezcan, por ejemplo a un mismo empleado, dentro de una función que luego será llamada con un trigger. Tal vez alguna o sugerencia guía?

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: hola, gracias ya logre solucionarlo! tuve que hacer un seleccionado count(*) :: integer.